# Why do they drink synthehol in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

Synthehol is a chemical variant of alcohol. It appears to have the same taste and smell as "real" alcohol to most individuals, but none of the intoxicating effects associated with alcohol. This being the case, why drink it?

Comment: For the same reason people drink low alcohol beer?

Comment: @Richard They didn't look at the label close enough before buying?

Comment: @coburne - Well yes, obviously.

Comment: Well, I don't know about you, but I'd rather not have a drunk helmsmen or engineer controlling a ship that runs delicate matter-antimatter combinations... ;)

Comment: @N.Soong -Things you never want to hear your helmsman say; "Hold my beer and watch this."

Comment: Kava is sedating and is primarily consumed to relax without disrupting mental clarity.-Wiki

Comment: @coburne - that actually happened to me in Germany, of all places. They actually love low-alcohol beer in Germany.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Gene Roddenberry spoke about the benefits of Synthehol in an [interview with CBS](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1fpb6_gene-roddenberry-interview_fun). Essentially, you get all the positives of alcohol consumption with none of the negatives:

> "We have invented, for the bar-room, something called *Synthenol* [sic],
>   which acts just the same as alcohol, makes you feel that you can be a
>   lover, or wise, or all the things that alcohol does, but with
>   the...**it's only temporary. You, with a force of will, you can shove
>   it aside and you're as sober as you ever were**"

---

Commander Data gives us a pretty good overview of why [Synthehol](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Synthehol) is seen as preferable to Alcohol in the TNG episode "[Relics](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/230.txt)"

- **It *is* intoxicating** but these effects can be 'easily dismissed' (by adrenalin, see below) if you need to return to duty.
- It's non-toxic and non-addictive.
- It looks, smells and tastes *similar* to alcohol, to all but a connoisseur.

> **SCOTT :** *Synthehol?*
>
> **DATA :** *Yes. It is an alcohol substitute which is now normally served
>   aboard starships. It simulates the appearance, smell, and taste of
>   alcohol, but the intoxicating affects can be easily dismissed.*

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) entry on Synthehol seems to draw heavily from the same quote;

[image: Synthehol]

The semi-canon "[Star Trek : The Starfleet Survival Guide](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Starfleet_Survival_Guide)" mentions that the effects of synthehol are 'neutralised' by adrenalin, therefore anyone thrust into a dangerous or life-threatening situation would become **instantly sober**:

> "Synthehol, **because it is easily neutralized by low volumes of natural
>   adrenaline**, poses far less risk to a patient."

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's as much of an acquired 'cultural' taste/norm as it is alcohol content. When you're in Idaho you eat potatoes and when you're in India you use a lot of curry... 'everyone else is doing it'.

Comment: @Morgan - Yes. If it's what you've got then you'll learn to like it better than the real thing, especially when you look at the benefits.

Comment: "but these effects can be easily dismissed" - do you know how this happens? Willpower? "Antidote"?

Comment: Reminds me of random book I read one time on Kindle, "The Future Perfect". It's a satirical dystopian future novel where people are able to eat as much as they want at parties by taking pills that containing food-eating stomach worms. Of course, if they forget to take the pill that kills them afterward, the worms will basically eat them alive...

Comment: @MarcusBitzl - The effects are dismissed when exposed to adrenalin according to Star Trek writer, David Mack.

Comment: Interesting that this was a Ferrengi invention...could explain the rapid improvement of diplomatic relations between them and the Federation.

Comment: I've been watching TNG for most of my life and I never thought about this. They've combined the effects of consuming alcohol, the effects of consuming cocaine after drinking too much alcohol, and the effects of a liver transplant....all in one drink. Miracle science, indeed.

Answer (score 12):

Many people -- myself included -- enjoy the taste of alcoholic beverages, but don't like to become intoxicated. Synthehol would allow us to drink more of them without suffering those consequences (or rather, without losing the ability to just shake them off at a whim).

Further, even when "off-duty" we spend the vast majority of our time watching Starfleet personnel on board active starships/space stations. How many times have you seen off-duty personnel being called to duty due to one emergency or another? Just like real world naval vessels, it's quite likely that Starfleet personnel are prohibited from drinking alcohol even off-duty while serving aboard an active ship, since even off-duty personnel can be called to duty in an emergency at any time (and yet even when awoken in the dead of night, they still seem to find the time to get into perfectly pristine uniforms, no matter how urgent the crisis...). Synthehol allows starship/space station personnel the enjoyment of drink, but still allow them to readily dismiss the effects and return to duty at a moment's notice.

That being said, for those who do want to get *truly* intoxicated there still are options, including Romulan ale (which more than once has been mentioned as being genuinely intoxicating -- not sure if it can't be made with synthehol, or if it just isn't). And while I can't cite specific examples right now, there have been times when we've visited planets and observed seemingly intoxicated patrons at bar establishments (pretty sure there's more than one example in the background in the episode where Picard is kidnapped by the artifact thieves, for example). The point being that while Starfleet personnel on board starships might be drinking synthehol, it seems the "real deal" is still readily available to those who want it (at least while they're not serving on a starship, anyway).

Comment: I know many, many people who drink. Some a lot and some a little but not a one would drink non-alcohol beer if they were in a situation where alcohol beer was inappropriate or not available. They drink water, pop, coffee, juice, etc., but not 'beer placebo'.

Comment: lol. Chief Engineers may be excluded. Bless Mr. Scott for being the rebel he is/was/will be.

Comment: @Morgan You're confusing real life with fiction. There is no such thing as synthehol here in the real world, those friends of yours who refuse non-alcoholic beer do so because that stuff tastes like bantha poo (and often smells like the insides of a tauntaun)! If there were synthehol -- a substance with all the same taste and smells as alcohol, but none of the intoxicating effects -- a lot of people (not all) would drink it; for the others (i.e. those who do want the intoxicating effects and aren't serving aboard and active starship) Star Trek is still full of real alcohol.

Comment: @Kromey -"You're confusing real life with fiction." No I'm not, Star Trek is real!

Comment: @MajorStackings - If you watch TOS: "The Cage", their CMO prescribes Captain Pike a chilled martini when he's looking stressed... :-)

Comment: -1.  Per Commander Data, as quoted by Richard, synthehol IS intoxicating.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - It's intoxicating but without resulting in drunkeness. I think the implication is that you get a nice "buzz" but that's all.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades You're right; what I meant was that you don't get "true drunk", in the sense that any effects of the synthehol can be easily shaken off. I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @Morgan: Your anecdotal evidence doesn't change that a certain small percentage of customers drinks alcohol-free beer.

Comment: @Morgan: Anecdotal evidence -- alcohol is one of my migraine triggers. But when I'm doing a BBQ, I *want* the taste of beer to go with the grilled meat, but I do *not* want to spend the rest of the evening with a splitting headache instead of socializing with my friends and neighbours. Non-alcoholic beer is fine with me. Not the real thing, but close enough. (At least if you pick the right brand.)

Comment: For all intensive purposes, alcohol free drinks are synthahol counter parts. Per canon, synthahol tastes horrible compare to alcohol, and many people claim to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: @cde "Many" people is a stretch. Picard was born and raised on a vineyard, and Scotty seems to be an aficionado. They're expert/edge cases, not common drinkers.

Comment: Damn near everyone that ever had a drink in star trek has complained on camera at least once.

Answer (score 5):

It's to explain how they could be hanging out in the bar all the time talking to Whoopie Goldberg and still jump up & be ready to duty when the alarm rang

Answer (score 2):

They do have real booze in TNG and DS9, as Miles O'Brien can attest, usually for off-duty. Picard shared a bottle of the real stuff with Scotty ("who do you think gave it to Guinan?"). On the original series Bones had his own recipe that he would "prescribe" to Kirk. There is also a black market for Romulan ale. I would imagine that in the Star Trek universe the negative health side effects of alcohol would be more easily treatable, so alcoholism isn't as much of a problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked which is **why people drink synthehol.**

Answer (score 1):

From my memory of the Second Edition Star Trek Encyclopedia:
Synthehol is an alcohol substitute invented by the Ferengi. It is functionally and flavorfully identical to alcohol with one difference: the effects of intoxication can be literally willed away. Although the exact mechanism for this drunkness-dismissal is never directly revealed, it was implied to merely require an internal act of willpower equivalent to making the decision to no longer be impaired.

Synthehol-based beverages were originally served by Ferengi prior to and during negotiations so as to allow them to drink heavily, thereby encouraging their soon-to-be opponents to do the same. When the time came to commence with deal-making, the Ferengi would suddenly be mysteriously sharp and unimpaired, while their opponents would be sloppy drunk and at a distinct disadvantage when it came to negotiating. Eventually this fact became widely known, nobody was willing to drink with Ferengi prior to striking a deal, and the Ferengi realized they could make more profit selling an alcohol you can choose whether to be intoxicated by than they ever made using it to tip negotiations in their favor.

Although I recall at least one non-canon Star Trek novel (Balance of Power, by Dafydd ab Hugh) making reference to a synthehol still in a student dorm room at Starfleet Academy, my impression from canon sources was that all synthehol-based drinks were produced by Ferengi or their agents and the secret of its production was closely guarded.

The reasons for synthehol's adoption over alcohol by Starfleet are obvious, however, as the question of allowing alcohol on-board sea-going vessels has presented a problem for terrestrial navies as long as they have existed. Allow alcohol, and morale increases dramatically, but so do the problems associated with intoxicated sailors on duty. Morale is a serious concern for the commander of any vessel, as Synthehol allows Starfleet to sidestep this problem neatly.

Comment: Can you substantiate your claims with some quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. My answer is based on my memories of the Second Edition Star Trek Encyclopedia, which is something I spent a lot of time reading when I was in Middle School 20 years ago but have long since given away.

Comment: Wasn't synthahol present in tos? That makes it a retcon to have the tng ferengi be the source. What was the original source then. ..