# What is the "green" in Tilly's 'green juice' in Star Trek: Discovery Season 1?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In Discovery episode 6 ("[Lethe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lethe_(episode))") Tilly and Burnham finish a run through the ship, Tilly wants to order a green juice with "extra green". Burnham cancels the order, asking for something healthier instead.

> **Tilly:** *Computer, green juice, extra green.*
>
> **Burnham:** *Computer, cancel that order. That's hardly the correct ratio of protein, carbohydrates, and fat. Computer, three egg-white breakfast burrito with black beans."*

**What is the "green", and why would one want extra of it?**

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: e.g. https://www.prevention.com/food-nutrition/healthy-eating/g20505685/green-juice-recipes/

Comment: There was nothing useful in the "After Trek" episode that accompanied the show. They didn't even discuss that scene.

Comment: Soylent Green is made of Orion people.   It's people!

Answer (score -2):

It's an alcoholic beverage that Scotty drinks. People often don't know it's name, they just say:
"What is it?"
"It's green"

Actually, it does have a name, Aldebran Whiskey.

Comment: This seems like a total guess (and one that's likely wrong). Can you provide any evidence to back it up?

Comment: Note that Burnham complains about it having an improper mixture of *"protein, carbohydrates, and fat"*. Nothing about it being alcoholic.

Comment: We don't know if they were "on duty" but if they were "on duty" then there's no way that it would be an alcoholic drink

Comment: Furthermore, Memory Alpha calls the stuff in the DIS episode "green juice", whereas Aldebaran Whiskey would surely have been referred to by name in some extra material, I'd have thought. Little homages and references are all over the place, someone would've made mention of it were it the case.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - I see no evidence that Memory Alpha have any more clue about the composition of this drink than anyone else.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - Other crewmen seem to be drinking green smoothies in the refectory.

Comment: I reject your canon and substitute my own, +1.

Comment: @Mazura - In whatever canon you want, people don't get shitfaced while they're on duty :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Senior officers can do w/e they want. [Are Starfleet officers allowed to drink on duty?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147055/are-starfleet-officers-allowed-to-drink-on-duty)

Comment: @Mazura - The top-rated answer explicitly states that they ***can't*** drink alcohol on duty.

Comment: You wrote it, I should hope you know what it says ;) "drinking alcohol on duty is frowned upon, both before and after the invention of synthehol. The only times it's tolerated are with the permission of the Captain or a senior officer."